# How to compress response in Webservices in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I am want to compress the response of a webmethod call. This compressed data should be decompressed by different mobile platform like iPhone, Android, Windows Phone 7 and Blackberry. I have checked different solution but did not find any proper solution. Actually we have a webmethod which gives data of around 20,000 records (which is in size around 2 MB). And we would like to to compress data to transfer over HTTP.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you should consider to change the infrastructure at its root. Having to transfer 20k record has to be avoided with some strategy ( paging for example )

Answer (score 1):

Since you are likely hosting this in IIS, you should be able to enable GZIP compression.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using GZip?
take a look at the following technet guide:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730629(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: are you writing to the response stream by yourself?